# How can I deallocate an irregular ***matrix without knowing it's size?

Tags: c, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to create a function
void destroy(int ***matrix); use to deallocate the matrix
And i dont know how can i deallocate it without knowing its sizes

I'd some ideas or an example of a code.

Comment: It's simple: You can't. Always when you allocate dynamically (unless you only allocate a single object) you must keep track of the size. Not only for freeing the memory but for all iteration over the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a convention that only pointers before a sentinel value (e.g. `NULL`) need to be freed.

```
void destroy (int ***matrix) {
    if (matrix == NULL) return;

    for (int i = 0; matrix[i]; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; matrix[i][j]; ++j) {
            free(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```